# PHP - Order in a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

```
<div class="row">

<?php
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE $filter exposure!='0' AND `status`='2' AND (clicks_left_micro>0 OR clicks_left_mini>0 OR clicks_left_standard>0 OR clicks_left_extended>0) ORDER BY exposure DESC");
while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($r)):

    echo "<div class='span4'> text here text here</div>";

endwhile;
?>

</div>
```

As you can see in the `$r` query, I am ordering by `exposure`. The exposure field can contain the numbers from `1-3`. What I am trying to do is to create a new row for each exposure number. Example:

Advertisements that have exposure = 1, will be in the first row
Below that, will be advertisements that have exposure = 2
And last, there will be advertisements that have exposure = 3

The way it is now, the advertisements/span4 divs are just being echoed out next to each other. I want to sort them inside the while loop in `<div class='row'></div>`

Comment: Check out [Grouping results under a heading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158727/grouping-results-under-a-heading). It uses the same principle.

Comment: `mysql_*` is _deprecated_, please use `PDO` (consistend, OO API, marginally slower) or `mysqli_*` (messy API, but fastest extension, very powerful, too) instead. Leave `mysql_*` (deprecated, unsafe) alone, and never look back

Comment: Like @EliasVanOotegem already said: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Virus721: obviousle not enough, since the deprecation of `mysql_*` has been [in the pipes for over 2 years](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/66726), plenty of time to get informed, update tuts and refs to documentation. Heck, even php.net has had a red warning box on their manual pages for ages, and still we see people using this extension every day _to write new code_, that will issue `E_DEPRECATED` warinings in PHP>=5.5

Comment: Yeah but in the real world few people will be using PHP 5.5. It's already a miracle when people are using 5.3...

Comment: @Virus721: I've been using 5.3 in my work environment(s) for years... And even if I didn't: writing future-proof code is _not_ a wasted effort, nor is leading by example. even If you're not getting the notices on your server, don't set a bad example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE $filter exposure!='0' AND `status`='2' AND (clicks_left_micro>0 OR clicks_left_mini>0 OR clicks_left_standard>0 OR clicks_left_extended>0) ORDER BY exposure DESC");
        $row1 = '';
        $row2 = '';
        $row3 = '';
        while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($r)):
             if($ar['exposure'] == 1)
                  $row1 .= '<span>Your code here for row 1</span>';
             else if($ar['exposure'] == 2)
                  $row2 .= '<span>Your code here for row 2</span>';
             else if($ar['exposure'] == 3)
                  $row3 .= '<span>Your code here for row 3</span>';
        endwhile;
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row2; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row3; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Of course you will have to adjust it to your needs, but this is the idea.

EDIT: As some other people have noticed, you should not use mysql_* functions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are ordered by exposure, you can simply do :

```
$curExpo = null;

while( ... ) {
    if( $curExpo !== $row['exposure']) {
        create new row
        $curExpo = $row['exposure'];
    }
}
```